# How to Get users by group from EconomicWebService SOAP

Tags: php, soap, wsdl, soap-client

Currenlty if i want to get accounts from a group i have to fetch all users then filter its group with php. Is there any way to fetch all user from a group. Like i have group 3 and 5 . I only need users from group 3 . Currently i am doing by iterating 15000 users then filtering in php loop

```
    $wsdl_url = 'https://api.e-conomic.com/secure/api1/EconomicWebservice.asmx?WSDL';
    $client = new SoapClient($wsdl_url, array("trace" => 1, "exceptions" => 1));            
    $client->ConnectWithToken(
        array(
                'token'    => '******',
                'appToken' => '******'
            )
        );
    $accounts = $client->Debtor_GetAll();
    
    foreach($accounts->Debtor_GetAllResult->DebtorHandle as $account)
    {
        
        $data = $client->Debtor_GetData(array('entityHandle' => $account));
        
        $user_id = $email = $name = $password = $vat_number = $phone = '';
        
        // Make sure required values are present (e-mail and ID)
        if(!isset($data->Debtor_GetDataResult->Number, $data->Debtor_GetDataResult->Email))
        {
            continue;
        }
        
        $user_id    = utf8_decode($data->Debtor_GetDataResult->Number);
        $email      = utf8_decode($data->Debtor_GetDataResult->Email);
       
        if(isset($data->Debtor_GetDataResult->Name))
        {
            $name = utf8_decode($data->Debtor_GetDataResult->Name);
        }
       
            
        if($data->Debtor_GetDataResult->DebtorGroupHandle->Number == 5){$i++;
        $userdata = array();
        $userdata['user_id'] = $user_id;
        $userdata['group_id'] = $data->Debtor_GetDataResult->DebtorGroupHandle->Number;
        $userdata['name'] = $name;
        echo    $userdata['name'];
        echo    "<br>";
         
        }
        
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass group id to find the users by group

```
$groupHandle= $client
            ->DebtorGroup_FindByNumber(array('number'=>$group_id))
            ->DebtorGroup_FindByNumberResult;
        $debtorHandles = $client->DebtorGroup_GetDebtors(array('debtorGroupHandle'=>$groupHandle))
            ->DebtorGroup_GetDebtorsResult
            ->DebtorHandle;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).